# postfix sender dependent relayhost

Tags: postfix-mta

I want a single sending address to use a different gmail account, and all others to use the default gmail account.

As most tutorials online say this should work, but postfix uses the default smtp user name and password for all emails...

Is there any documentation for postfix that can help?
Sender dependent tls encryption also appears to not be an option... am I wrong?

```
### main.cf ###
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps=/etc/postfix/senderDependentRelayHostMap

smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_...

### senderDependentRelayHostMap ###
test@gmail.com smtp.gmail.com:587

### sasl_password ###
#per sender email stmp username and password
test@gmail.com test@gmail.com:testPass
#default route
smtp.gmail.com:587 default@site.com:defaultPass
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure `Sender-Dependent SASL authentication` in Postfix. Please add the following lines to your `main.cf`

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf    
#...
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes 
smtp_sasl_password_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd 
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587 
smtp_tls_security_level = may 
smtp_sasl_security_options =
#...
```

and create `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` with the following content.

```
/^test@gmail.com$/  test@gmail.com:testPass
/^/                 default@site.com:defaultPass
```

Reload postfix.

If you send a mail to `someone@yahoo.com` from `test@gmail.com` using the following command

```
echo "Hi Everyone"|mail -s "Test email" -r "test@gmail.com" someone@yahoo.com
```

then your postfix server will authenticate using `test@gmail.com`'s password configured in `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`. Mails from all other senders will authenticate using `default@site.com:defaultPass`

Ref: [Postfix docs](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_sender)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Closer, I can send from the test account, but it causes all other emails from the default email account to get queued for delivery, indefinitely.  I was hoping for the flexibility to send from gmail or yahoo as needed (sender dependent relay hosts), but I don't require it.